# i have a problem loading a code in flutter. any time i run it , it says FlutterError

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

i tried to wrap my cintainer with a sizedBox but it threw an error. i honestly don't know what to do

```dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, file_names, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, use_full_hex_values_for_flutter_colors
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RowItemsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RowItemsWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          height: 180,
          // width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xfff5f9fd),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0xff47569).withOpacity(0.3),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                )
              ]),
          child: Row(children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 70),
                  height: 120,
                  width: 130,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF475269),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "images/1.png",
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Nike Shoe',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff475269),
                        fontSize: 23,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Men's Shoe",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff475269).withOpacity(0.8),
                          fontSize: 16),
                    )
                  ]),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "\$50",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 70),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xff475269),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.cart_fill_badge_plus,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message do you get

Answer (score 0):

`Spacer()` isnt suitable for your current widget tree. Replace the `Spacer` with SizedBox. You can use LayoutBuilder on scaffold body to get the layout- constrains .

```dart
class RowItemsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RowItemsWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        
        children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          height: 180,
          // width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xfff5f9fd),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0xff47569).withOpacity(0.3),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                )
              ]),
          child: Row(children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 70),
                  height: 120,
                  width: 130,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF475269),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "images/1.png",
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Nike Shoe',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff475269),
                        fontSize: 23,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Men's Shoe",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff475269).withOpacity(0.8),
                          fontSize: 16),
                    )
                  ]),
            ),
            // Spacer(),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "\$50",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 70),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xff475269),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.cart_fill_badge_plus,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `Spacer()` inside a widget that doesn't have a defined size. There were many redundant widgets in your code, e.g. `Stack()` and the inner `Row()`. Below you can find an optimised version of your code.

```
class RowItemsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RowItemsWidget({super.key});

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        // width: 200,
        height: 180,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Color(0xfff5f9fd),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xff47569).withOpacity(0.3),
              blurRadius: 5,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 70),
              height: 120,
              width: 130,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF475269),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/1.png",
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Nike Shoe',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff475269),
                      fontSize: 23,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Men's Shoe",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff475269).withOpacity(0.8),
                        fontSize: 16),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "\$50",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 70),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff475269),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.cart_fill_badge_plus,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```